# Crop out the top of an image numpy (or scipy)

Tags: python, numpy

There is a header on the top of an image I have. I am trying to crop it out.

The shape of my image is

(600, 960)

```
def crop(image):
    lx, ly = image.shape
    return image[:, 200:ly]
```

The header is 200px in height and is at the very top of the image. Any ideas? The above code weirdly returns the exact same image given to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing axes; try:

```py
def crop(image):
    return image[200:,:]
```

Comment: `image[200:]` ought to be enough as the rows are the first dimension; numpy treats the omitted trailing dimensions as unmodified.